# Google Analytics API Insufficient Permission

Tags: api, permissions, analytics

I am searching the google analytics with api

Here is my test code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('xxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'xxx.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("xxx.json");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);

try{
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
}catch(google_Service_Exception $e){
    $e->getMessage();
    print_r($e->getMessage());

}
```

And the results is :

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}],"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission"}}
```

I use Embed API to test my account permission is ok, then I don't understand why?

Can Anyone tell what permission I need to setup for my app in api console. ? thank you very much.